# Modify code to create file in newly created folder

Tags: python

From https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26714/can-i-record-a-24-hour-video-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-camera-module I'm attempting to modify code :

```
import io
import itertools
import picamera

def outputs():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield io.open('file%02d.h264' % i, 'wb')

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 360)
    camera.framerate = 24
    for output in camera.record_sequence(
            outputs(), quality=20, bitrate=750000):
        while output.tell() < 1048576:
            camera.wait_recording(0.1)
        if output.name == 'file99.h264':
            break
```

This code will "produce 100 files rolling over once each reaches >1Mb,"

I'm attempting to modify so that once file reaches > 5Mb a new file is created. Directories ranging from 1 to 100 should be created with each containing a max of 100 files. Here is my progress so far :

```
import io
import itertools
import picamera
import os

def outputs():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield io.open('file%02d.h264' % i, 'wb')

for i in range(1 , 101) :

    os.mkdir(str(i))
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (640,480)
        camera.framerate = 24
        for output in camera.record_sequence(
                outputs(), quality=20, bitrate=750000):
            while output.tell() < 5048576:
                camera.wait_recording(0.1)
            if output.name == 'file99.h264':
```

How to create the file in the newly created folder and check this newly created folder that it contains 100 files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the first piece of code and modify its `output` function:

```
def outputs():
    dir_count = 0
    current_dir = 'dir{}'

    for i in itertools.count(1):
        if not (i % 100):
            dir_count += 1
            os.mkdir(current_dir.format(dir_count))
        yield io.open((current_dir + '/file{:02d}.h264').format(current_dir, i % 100), 'wb')
```

Or shorter:

```
def outputs():
    yield from (
        io.open('dir{}/file{:02d}.h264'.format(dir, i), 'wb')
        for dir in itertools.count(1)
        for i in range(100)
        if os.makedirs('dir{}'.format(dir), exist_ok=True) is None
    )
```

When the number of files per directory is 10, the following files will be created:

```
$ ls -h ./*
./dir1:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir10:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir11:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir12:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir13:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir14:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir15:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir16:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir17:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir18:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir19:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir2:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir20:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

./dir21:
file00.h264 file02.h264 file04.h264 file06.h264 file08.h264
file01.h264 file03.h264 file05.h264 file07.h264 file09.h264

# the list goes on and on...
```

*WARNING!* Do not forget to *close the opened files* because there will be *a lot* of them, and you'll get an error about too many files being open at the same time if you don't close them.